# How can I implement LRU cache in my maya scene using python?

Tags: python, caching, maya, python-decorators, lru

I am trying to implement LRU cache in my python program , I want to store object name and their types that are present in my maya scene into a LRU cache, then i want to create two functions which will return names and objectTypes.

Comment: Do you want to store this beween maya sessions or only within one session?

Comment: @haggikrey I want to store it betweeen maya sessions , also sorry for the late response

Comment: One way would be to store the data in a dictionary and save it in a workspace variable. This way you can always access it and it is saved in the preferences.

Comment: @haggikrey Thanks for the response, but i was looking for lru_cache_decorator in my program, I have created a cache which store scene data and now i want to write two functions which will access the lru_cache and print names and object types.

Comment: @haggikrey Can you elaborate a bit your answer tho ? Are you saying i should write a cache class and then store the data in it and also is there any way i can store it in the cache using decorator and then access elements from there ?

Comment: If you write a function to access the data and one to save the data these functions can save/read from an workspace variable. I'll add an answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Ah okay i see thanks for your answer , also if i want it's lifecycle only for one sessions in this case eventually data will be stored in a database file which will be stored in memory and not in the cache right, it'll be faster but can i store it in the temp memory for faster execution even if it's only valid for one single session ?

Comment: Sure, you can create a global module variable which will be alive as long as the module is not reloaded or maya is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I mean `optinoVar` instead of `workspaceVariable`. In your functions you could easily do something like this (I use pymel for simplicity):

```
def readData():
    data = pm.optionVar.get("yourData", {})
    return json.loads(data)

def writeData(**newData):
    data = pm.optionVar.get("yourData", {})
    data[key] = newData[key]
    pm.optionVar.set("yourData", json.dumps(data))
```

Something like that, of course that depends a lot on your data layout.